# Open book decompositions in dimension 4

Tags: differential-topology, 4-manifolds

The question about the existence of open book decompositions for a closed oriented $n$-dimensional manifold seems to be answered in all dimensions except dimension $4$, where as far as I can tell the situation seems to be quite mysterious.
By playing around with the definition one can see that the signature has to vanish and the Euler characteristic has to agree with the Euler characteristic of a surface. Since the situation does not seemed to be resolved yet, these are probably not the only restrictions.

So my questions are:

1. What is the state of the art about open book decompositions in dimension $4$?
2. Do there exist requirements that ensure that a $4$-manifold admits an open book decomposition
3. Do there exist requirements that ensure that a $4$-manifold admits an open book decomposition up to stabilization i.e. connected sum with certain other $4$-manifolds
4. As a non-trivial example, does the product of two surfaces of genus at least $2$ admit an open book decomposition? Does it admit one up to stabilization?

Answer (score 5):

Nice question; there's not much known in general. The signature obstruction you mention goes back to Winkelnkemper (Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 79 (1973), 45–51) and is sufficient for *simply connected* $4n$-manifolds when $n>1$.  The general high-dimensional case there are further obstructions; see Quinn (Topology 18 (1979), no. 1, 55–73), Neumann (Topology 14 (1975), no. 3, 237–244) and Lawson (Topology 17 (1978), no. 2, 189–192).  It's possible that Quinn's obstructions are stable obstructions; you'd have to read the paper to find out.

For your question 3: Simply connected $4$-manifolds of signature $0$ are stably diffeomorphic to connected sums of $S^2 \times S^2$ or the twisted bundle $S^2 \tilde{\times} S^2$; those connected sums have open book decomposition.  So simple connectivity would suffice.

Finally, there's an interesting connection between open books and Engel structures in dimension $4$; see Colin-Presas-Vogel (Algebraic & Geometric Topology 18 (2018) 4275–4303).

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the answer of Danny Ruberman: One source that summarizes the state of the art pretty well is given by Andrew Ranicki in [High dimensional knot theory](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=ranicki&s5=high%20dimensional&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=3&mx-pid=1713074). In Chapter 29 he reformulates the obstruction by Quinn in terms of surgery theory. His invariant, called asymmetric signature $\sigma^*$,  refines the signature invariant for non-simply connected manifolds. It is proven in all dimensions including dimension 4 that if an open book exists then $\sigma^*$ vanishes. Also in all dimensions except dimension 4, that the reverse implication holds. Using that formulation it easier to see that  $\sigma^*$ is in fact a stable invariant up to stabilization with $S^2 \times S^2$. With Quinn's original more geometric approach it was not as easy to see that.

We know that Quinn's proof to show the reverse implication does not work in dimension 4 for several reasons. However the statement might still be true. We have a proof outline with Marc Kegel which we are working out at the moment to show that any 4 manifold with vanishing asymmetric signature $\sigma^*$ carries an open book after stabilization.

Comment: Surely, using "double null foliation" or some generalisation should help answer all questions. The "double null foliation" structure should allow to lift the problem to a conformally Anosov flow ("bi-G_2-structure" (perhaps a tamed one in the sense of D. Joyce)) on a characteristic 7-manifold associated to the given 4-mfld (via Einstein-Yang-Mills equation or a deformation of). By using the structure given by the conformally Anosov flow (characteristic invariants), one should be able to extract necessary informations, given answer to each question and even more.

Comment: I had some thoughts about these questions some time ago. It is just recently that I saw the link with Anosov flow theory and this brings me back to that problem...

Comment: ...bring me to that problem *again*. In any case, it's still very speculative. But, I think that it may pay to think about the lines of thoughts...

Comment: There should be a close link between the characteristic invariants of the conformally Anosov flow that we are talking about and the spinorial torsion studied by A. Moreno (see Algebraic Torsion in higher-dimensional contact manifolds, arXiv:1711.01562). Unfortunately, I have not yet had the time to read this document with all the necessary seriousness. It would be very interesting, from my point of view, to have the opinion (or better, the teaching) of A. Moreno (or any other SOBD expert) on this subject.

Comment: Furthermore, I am convinced that T. Walpuski and, in general, any specialist in higher dimensional gauge theory, should have a lot to say about these lines of ideas, provided that these lines carry the value that I glimpse... Although these lines of ideas could have been known and developed by some for a long time... Being still an apprentice, I could therefore be marveling at junk...

Comment: By design itself, if such an idea of ​​the conformally Anosov flow is worth dwelling on for a few moments, then it should be clear to any worthy student of the C. Ehresmann school, headed by E. Ghys (sincerely sorry to seem to speak so lightly of such illustrious people). Furthermore, it was by reading with much more attention the article by E. Ghys (L'invariant de Godbillon-Vey, séminaire Bourbaki : volume 1988/89 exposés 700-714 155-181, 1989) on the Godbillon-Vey invariant that the consideration of the Anosov flow appeared essential to me.

Comment: In this same vein, the entire Heidelberg team, around A. Wiennhard, should see things very clearly, particularly for the construction of the characteristic phase 7-manifold. In this case too, I could be marveling at objects that are obsolete in their eyes...